# Why is the use of @uses tag in docblocks discouraged?

Tags: codex

See [inline documentation standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/#phpdoc-tags)

> Note: This tag has been used in the past, but should no longer be
>   used.

What gives?

I am building a plugin to build a codex from the source of a plugin/theme and i think the `@uses` tag would be perfect for linking functions to hooks and hooks to functions.

Comment: Don't see a good reason for it. Personally I just ignore some suggestions made by the WP core developer team. In short: I use `@uses` and will continue to do so. Last but not least, it is your plug-in, not core code, so use `@uses` as you want I say.

Comment: Totally agree with @ialocin And to be really really honest, Wordpress coding standards are a mess. Even the core developers don't adhere to it. `@uses` is valid and not depreciated in any way in doc blocks

Comment: Yeah but the point would be if i release this opensource then i would want to stick to WP standards so that the plugin could be used on any other plugin effectively.

Comment: Which standards? I have seen really bad plugins on wordpress.org which totally does not stick to any kind of standard. The person who wrote that piece of garbage in the documentation should explain **WHY** we cannot use `@uses`. I'm busy with a huge pagination plugin based on PSR-4 standards. I want to see that been declined from the respitory on wordpress.org.

Comment: Well according to their standards, but my whole point is, i want to use @uses to double link functions to actions etc and i don't want to add this as a feature of the plugin if WP are telling people not to use [@]uses at all.  [@]uses seems perfect for this feature and it was it's intended use by phpdocumentor http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.uses.pkg.html I just want to know if there is a good reason why they are telling people not to use it before i add this as a feature to the plugin.

Comment: There is no official documentation that I know of which gives any type of reason why `@uses` should not be used. Just to on standards, Wordpress supposedly uses PEAR coding standards, now in that same page you are referring to in your question, there is this line *Only when the new – external – PSR-5 recommendations are finalized, will across-the-board changes be considered, such as deprecating certain tags.* Want to talk about standards :-)

Comment: `@uses` is practically useless, because every parser for _find usages_ is more accurate = never out of sync.

Comment: @toscho I get the point, but shouldn't - perfect world and such - the documentation be up to date, ergo in sync.

Comment: @ialocin Yes, but hat should be limited to really useful cases. [`WP_Query::get_posts()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7b5ae9022513699a0c337c7af389e12e0947e9a9/wp-includes/query.php#L2380) would need dozens of `@uses` tags, the doc block would be almost unreadable – without any real benefit. This is pointless for code that changes as fast as WordPress.

Comment: I use `@uses` when I call some class method with `call_user_func` and IDE sais that method is unused. With `@uses` IDE understands that specific method is used and doesn't complain.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure but I guess it's because usage of `@uses` can be covered with `@see`

From phpDocumentor docs

> @uses is very similar to @see, see the documentation for @see for details on format and structure. The @uses tag differs from @see in two ways. @see is a one-way link, meaning the documentation containing a @see tag contains a link to other documentation. The @uses tag automatically creates a virtual @usedby tag in the other documentation that links to the documentation containing the @uses tag. In other words, it is exactly like @see, except a return link is added automatically.
>
> The other difference is that @uses only accepts one element to link to, and a description of that element.

Probably, WP people decided that it isn't worth to have 2 tags so similar but only maintain one.

BTW, `@uses` is a fine tag. If you want to support it just do it and document its support in documentation.

Comment: " except a return link is added automatically."  This is why i want to use it, because this is what i want to use it for.  I want to use this feature to be able to scan any plugin, so i would want to stick to what devs will be using.  If only i could get them to remove that line from their docs.

Comment: So, as said, use it. PS, do you know the existence of https://github.com/rmccue/WP-Parser ?

Comment: +1 But, they are actually not that similar, right? Thats rhetorical of course. And to treat them as equal, as the documentation standard does, is just utterly stupid. @StiofanO'Connor Really, just use it and don't care.

Comment: *If only i could get them to remove that line from their docs* That is like farting against a tornado. Don't drive yourself mad over something you cannot change. Until there is no official documentation which documents the depreciation of `@uses`, you must use it as you wish. @StiofanO'Connor